# creating Sequelize Relations/associations

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have created the following tables:

```
user TABLE [id, name, email, dob, zipcode, created_on]
results TABLE [id, assessment_id, q_id, response, created_on]
```

Next in my DB I created an foreign key association between results => assessmentId and assessments => id

In my code I have created my object which contains all of the information I want saved, it looks like this:

```
results = {
    name: 'bruce',
    email: 'kldf@sdklj.com',
    dob: 10/24/84,
    zipcode: '55555',
    responses: {
        {
            qId: 'S1Q01',
            response: 2
        }, {
            qId: 'S1Q02',
            response: 0
        }
    }
}
```

My model definitions:

Assessment Model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var assessment = sequelize.define('assessments', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        dob: DataTypes.DATE,
        zipcode: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        created_on: DataTypes.DATE
    });

    return assessment;
};
```

Result model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var results = sequelize.define('results', {
        assessmentId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        qId: DataTypes.STRING,
        response: DataTypes.STRING,
        created_on: DataTypes.DATE
    });

    return results;
};
```

model index

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
var models = [
    'Assessment',
    'Result'
];


models.forEach(function(model) {
    module.exports[model] = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
});

(function(m) {
    m.Assessment.hasMany(m.Result);
})(module.exports);

module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;
```

Okay, I think all of that is correct based on the limited documentation I could find.

Lastly on my server I try to accept the POST request and persist the results in the DB however only the Assessment model is saved, the Result models are dropped.

```
router.post('/assessment', function(req, res) {
    var response;
    var assessment = Assessment.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
        created_on: new Date()
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        return function() {
            for(i=0; i<req.body.responses.length; i++) {
                response.build({
                    qId: req.body.responses[i].id,
                    response: req.body.responses[i].response,
                    created_on: new Date()
                });
                assessment.setResults(response);
            }
            res.send(200);
        }
    })
```

What am I missing? I can't find any documentation on how to actually persist the associated tables data, only documentation on how to get the associated table data.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this isn't the correct way to do this relationship but I found if I manually set the foreign key value it works fine.

```
router.post('/assessment', function(req, res) {
    var assessment = Assessment.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
        created_on: new Date()
    })
    .then(function(sourceData) {
        for(var i = 0; i < req.body.responses.length; i++) {
            var response = req.body.responses[i];
            var responseObj = Response.build({
                assessmentId: sourceData.dataValues.id,
                qId: response.id,
                response: response.response,
                created_on: new Date()
            });
            responseObj
                .save()
                .then(function() {
                    if(i === req.body.responses.length) {
                        res.send(200);
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    res.send(500, { error: err });
                    return;
                });
        }
    });
```

If anyone knows a better way to do this that doesn't require me to manually set the foreign key value please let me know.